# Can Zend Framework trigger redirect to route with query?

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework

Is it possible to set some query before redirect?

```
$this->redirector->gotoRoute(
            array('slug' => $theme['slug']),
            'theme'
        );
```

I would like to redirect which is:

```
  /theme/theme-name-slug?foo=bar
```

I was trying redirect to raw url but question mark is encoded and url is incorrect. I thought that Zend framework and Zend framework2 has similar redirect:

```
   $this->redirect()->toRoute(
            'categorie/default',
            array(
                'action' => 'category'
            ),
            array( 'query' => array(
                'foo' => 'bar'
            ))
        );
```

any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.